# C++ Find a node with zero in-degree in graph

Tags: c++, graph, nodes

I have implemented a graph using map

```
map<char,vector<char> > M;
```

Now, I am getting edges one by one and I am pushing them into graph like this

```
addEdge(char a,char b){
M[a].push_back(b);
}
```

I want to find the all the nodes with zero in degree. What can be the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if we take another map 'indegree' as shown in the following code, and increase the count, if the character appear as the terminating end of edge, then we can find the node with indegree 0.

```
map<char,vector<char> > M;
map<char,int> indegree;     
void addEdge(char a,char b){    
        M[a].push_back(b);                  
        indegree[b]++;
}
void show(){
        for(map<char,vecotr<char> > :: iterator it=M.begin();it!=M.end();it++){
                if(indegree[it->first]==0)
                        cout<<it->first<<endl;
        }
}
```

Another method will be to predefine an array of size 256, and follow the same procedure as above.

```
map<char,vector<char> > M;
int arr[256]={0};
void addEdge(char a,char b){    
        M[a].push_back(b);                  
        arr[b]++;
}
void show(){
        for(map<char,vecotr<char> > :: iterator it=M.begin();it!=M.end();it++){
                if(arr[it->first]==0)
                        cout<<it->first<<endl;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `vector<char> L` which will store the final nodes.

1. Initiate it to contain all the nodes.
2. For each edge (a,b): If b is in `L`, remove it from `L`.

Comment: We don't have any info about the nodes initially. As a new edge will come, we will get to know the two nodes of the graph.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have nodes with zero degree in a graph represented by a data structure containing only edges.
So if your graph is fully described by M[], you are guaranteed to have no nodes of zero degree.

Comment: i think he meant 0 in-degree, aka no edges go to a node, only come out of it

Comment: If this is the case, let's wait for refining the question. My statement is boringly true.